# How Do i Check Who Invited The User That Left Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So im making a Invite Logger Bot and i have a issue where for the Leave Event Nothing Happens, I want it to check who invited the person that left the server and to add 1 to the Leave Schema in the Mongo Database.

Here's My Code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (member) => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('843465196827967498');
    member.guild.fetchInvites().then(async guildInvites => { //get all guild invites
        guildInvites.each(async invite => { //basically a for loop over the invites
            if(invite.uses != client.invites[invite.code]) { //if it doesn't match what we stored:
                channel.send(`${member.user.tag} Left Invited By ${invite.inviter.tag}`)
                client.invites[invite.code] = invite.uses

                const req = await InviteLogger.findOne({
                    ServerID: member.guild.id,
                    UserID: invite.inviter.id
                })

                if(!req) return;

                const doc = await InviteLogger.findOneAndUpdate({ServerID: member.guild.id, UserID: invite.inviter.id},{ $inc: { Leave: 1 } }, {new: true});
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Have you [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQuK.png) the [`privileged intents`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)?

Comment: @Toasty I Have Enabled It

Comment: And still not working?

Comment: Yh Its Still Not Working

Comment: Is the event getting triggered?